# Contour integral of $z^n(1-z)^m$ around circle of radius 2

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, contour-integration

The problem is $\int z^n (1-z)^m$ along the circle contour parameterised by $2e^{it}$, $t = 0$ to $2\pi$, where $n, m < 0$ are integers.

I've used the keyhole contour argument to show that the radius of the circle doesn't matter as long as it's no less than 2, and the notes say this is useful. We can effectively set our own value $R > 2$ for the radius, so the value of the integral is independent of the radius of the contour. I don't know how to proceed from here.

We were told not to use the residue theorem.

(I asked this yesterday but had a typo in my equation which resulted in a different problem).

Comment: Are $n$ and $m$ integers?

Comment: Yes, $n$ and $m$ are integers

Answer (score 1):

Hint: consider the limit as $R \to \infty$.

Comment: I've noticed that the integral is independent of the radius and tried considering $R \to \inf$ but didn't get anywhere. Could you help me out?

Comment: Using the parametrization $z = R e^{it}$, you should get something of the form
$$ R^{1+n+m} \int_0^{2\pi} \ldots \; dt$$
where the $\ldots$ is uniformly bounded as $R \to \infty$.